# Running multiple query concurrently

Tags: mysql, sql, events, stored-procedures

I've have a event which runs every morning at 1 AM.
The aim of the event is to do some calculation on the database and save it in a table.

I have a procedure, say `spCalc` which takes a unique `mission_id` as parameter. i have to calculate for 5 missions, so i have to execute the procedure like

```
call spCalc(1);
 call spCalc(2);
 .. 
call spCalc(5);
```

Can i run this stored procedures concurrently so i can insert into a table more faster.

**Update:** 
The reason why i'm inserting data a table is:
I've to generate reports with more than 10 lakhs of records and to join more than 30 tables, as you know, it will take couple of hours to generate a report. We want to reduce this delay.

I'm doing some calculation like , i need to use max() function and to process all the data to find the highest. It would take lot of time when we process all the data.

So what we decided is to run the calculations every day morning and to save it, so it would be faster to retrieve.

Comment: Can you change your sp to take a list of ids?

Comment: Yes i can. But will it help me to reach a solution @DanBracuk

Comment: If the bulk of the time is spent inserting into the table, then concurrency probably won't help.  If you are doing lots of other work, and the insert is just one step, then concurrency might help.  Try it out and see.

Comment: I second what @DanBracuk is getting at.  You could either have it accept a list of id's or pull the id's through a query in your stored procedure from a table.  You should generally avoid single calls in favor of set based thinking.  Refactor the spCalc to make calculations  on all of your id's grouping your results somehow.  If you post code (or psuedo) we can help.